# Неверная кодировка в post запросе requests

Tags: python, django

изучаю django и хочу сделать форму для заказа такси с сайта, есть 3 поля для ввода номер телефона, адрес подачи и адрес назначения, при нажатии кнопку отрабатывает функция которая шлёт post запрос на сервер такси для создания заказа, но когда забиваю адрес подачи на английском языке всё нормально заказ создается, а на русском ни как вот код:

```
def ping_pong(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        after_15_minutes = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=15)
        data_param = 'phone=' + request.POST['tel'] + '&' + 'source=' + request.POST['source'] + '&' + 'source_time=' + after_15_minutes.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        print(data_param)
        sign_hash = hashlib.md5(bytes(data_param + sign, "UTF-8")).hexdigest()
        print(data_param.encode("UTF-8"))
        r = requests.post('https://777777.ddns.net:8089/common_api/1.0/create_order',
                         data=data_param,
                         headers={'Signature': sign_hash},
                         verify=False)
        print(r.text)

        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

когда передаю русские символы в поле source то выходит ошибка

```
Exception Value:'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 25-32: Body ('ТЕСТОВЫЙ') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.
```

Делаю data=data_param.encode("UTF-8") заказ создается но в программу приходит кракозябра вместо русских символов.

Comment: Посмотрите на кодировку ответа с помощью r.encoding

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 по умолчанию в utf-8, попробуйте убрать явную кодировку из sign_hash

Answer (score 0):

или передать кодировку в headers принудительно - должно заработать: 'Content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'}

Comment: Попробовал, не получилось та же ошибка

Comment: а если принудительно декодировать и кодировать data_param.decode('latin-1') и потом data_param.encode('utf-8')

Comment: тут на каком-то этапе запрос уходит на местную локальную кодировку и она совсем не utf-8

Comment: Я заметил что проблема именно там где идут параметры в пост запрос data=data_param а не там где они хэшируются

Comment: если передать как текст: r = requests.post(...., data=dict(data=text))

Comment: а если data_param.decode('utf-8') - это ведь данные от пользователя....

Comment: Да я так пробывал запрос проходит на сервер но в поле где должен быть адрес подачи выходит какие то левые символы, а не русский текст а вот английский текст приходит верно

Comment: А нет я делал encode а не decode

Comment: вот что-то мне кажется decode Или костыль передачей как текст.

Comment: Чуть позже буду у ноутбука и проверю как получиться

Comment: с кодировкой надо понять что ждет сервер, Heroku ждет текст в request и тут возможно так же

Comment: source=%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A2 вот так мне надо передавать слово ТЕСТ а я передаю через питон source=\xd0\xa2\xd0\x95\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa2 это какая то кодировка другая ?

Comment: словил сниффером параметры которые идут в запросе так там phone=89178719723&source=РўР•РЎРў&source_time=20200129233108

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить `urllib.parse.quote(request.POST['source'])`, и тогда кодировалась строка правильно.